# C++ - Parsing number from std::string

Tags: c++

I need to iterate through a shopping list which I have put into a vector and further separate each line by the quantity and item name. How can I get a pair with the number as the first item and the item name as the second?

Example:

```
vector<string> shopping_list = {"3 Apples", "5 Mandarin Oranges", "24 Eggs", "152 Chickens"}
```

I'm not sure how big the number will be so I can't use a constant index.

Ideally I would like a vector of pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function to split quantity and item like following:

```
#include <sstream>

auto split( const std::string &p ) {
    int num;
    std::string item;

    std::istringstream  ss ( p);
    ss >>num ; // assuming format is integer followed by space then item
    getline(ss, item); // remaining string
    return make_pair(num,item) ;
}
```

Then use `std::transform` to get vector of pairs :

```
std::transform( shopping_list.cbegin(),
                   shopping_list.cend(),
                   std::back_inserter(items), 
                   split );
```

[*`See Here`*](http://rextester.com/ZEH85148)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::stringstream` as follows.

```
vector< pair<int,string> > myList;
for(int i=0;i<shopping_list.size();i++) {
    int num;
    string item;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<shopping_list[i];
    ss>>num;
    ss>>item;
    myList.push_back(make_pair(num,item));
    ...
}
```

`num` is your required number.

Comment: I end up with an error that there's no = operator for stringstream.

Comment: Yeah that is an << not an =. sorry

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following solution without `stringstream` just as alternative solution

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> shopping_list = { "3 Apples", "5 Mandarin Oranges", "24 Eggs", "152 Chickens" };
    vector< pair<int, string> > pairs_list;

    for (string s : shopping_list)
    {
        int num;
        string name;
        int space_pos = s.find_first_of(" ");
        if (space_pos == std::string::npos)
            continue; // format is broken : no spaces

        try{
            name = s.substr(space_pos + 1);
            num = std::stoi(s.substr(0, space_pos));
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            continue; // format is broken : any problem
        }
        pairs_list.push_back(make_pair(num, name));
    }

    for (auto p : pairs_list)
    {
        cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```